# FogBugz XML API (Cases:)

Tags: fogbugz, fogbugz-api

I'm consuming the [FogBugz XML API](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/) but I have a problem. I'm able to create new cases, open created cases, search cases etc through my app. The problem consist of when getting the payload I can get the body of the case using the following piece of code:

```
        string fbToken = LogOnFogBugz();
        string param = "";

        param += "cmd=search";
        param += "&token=" + fbToken;
        param += "&q="+ "appID["+appID+"]";
        param += "&cols=sTitle,sStatus,sLatestTextSummary";

        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fbUrl + param);
        httpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/xml";
        httpWebRequest.ContentLength = 0;

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(streamReader);

 var cases = from c in doc.Descendants("case")
                    select new
                        {
                            CaseNumber = c.Attribute("ixBug").Value,
                            CaseTitle = (string)c.Element("sTitle"),
                            CaseStatus = (string)c.Element("sStatus"),
                            CaseText = (string)c.Element("sLatestTextSummary")
                        };
```

but If I edit the case and add text to it, I only get last entered text as (`sLatestTextSummary`) implies.

How can I get the whole text from a case using the XML API.

**Example:**

> Opened by xxx xxx 4/4/2012 (Today) 10:31 AM
>   ------------------------->Blah Blah Blah
>
> Assigned to xxx xxxx by xxx xxx 4/4/2012 (Today) 10:31 AM
>
> Edited by xxx xxx 4/4/2012 (Today) 2:00 PM
>   ---------------------------->New text.

I'm only getting `{new text}`.

Thanks in advance.

Ed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to include `events` as one of your `cols` arguments.
Then for each case you will also have to iterate over the events to get the text out of them.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the correct direction. I missed that (Element) on the payload.

Comment: Worth pointing out here that if you just need the "Opened by" or "Edited by" and not the actual "Blah Blah" text of the event, you'll want to use `minievents`. This will save time and server load.